# Is there a good tool for Makefile generation?

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform, makefile

I'm looking for a tool which can generate a [Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)#Makefile) for a C/C++ project for different compilers ([GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection), [Microsoft Visual C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B), [C++Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2BBuilder), etc.) and different platforms (Windows, Linux, and Mac).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Other suggestions you may want to consider:

- [Scons](http://www.scons.org/) is a cross-platform, cross-compiler build library, uses Python scripting for the build systems. Used in a variety of large projects, and performs very well.
- If you're using [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29), [QMake](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html) is a nice build system too.
- [CMake](https://cmake.org/) is also pretty sweet.
- Finally, [if all else fails...](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=cross+platform+build+system)

Answer (score 8):

Try [Automatic Makefile Generator](http://www.robertnz.net/genmake.htm#Details).

It has support for the following compilers:

- Borland 3.1
- Borland 5.0
- Borland 5.0, 16 bit
- Borland 5.5
- Borland 5.6
- Borland 5.8
- CC
- GNU g++
- GNU g++, dynamic library
- Intel 5, 6, 7 for Linux
- Intel 5, 6, 7 for Linux, dynamic library
- Intel 5, 6, 7 for Windows
- Intel 8,9,10 for Linux
- Intel 8,9,10 for Linux, dynamic library
- Intel 8,9 for Windows
- Intel 10 for Windows
- Visual C++ 5
- Visual C++ 6, 7, 7.1
- Visual C++ 8
- Open Watcom
- Watcom 10A
- Watcom 10A, 16 bit

Answer (score 4):

I've used [Bakefile](http://www.bakefile.org/index.html) before with some success. It's fairly simple and seems to work well.

Answer (score 4):

[CMake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) is the only tool which can actually generate real [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) projects (i.e., not "Makefile"-projects which call out to an external tool), and which automatically recreates the projects when the build input file ([CMakeLists.txt](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#organization)) changes.

[SCons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCons) performance issues are well-known and a thoroughly debated topic on the SCons mailing lists.

Answer (score 4):

I would vote for [OMake](http://omake.metaprl.org). It fixes all complains I had with GNU make:

- it's a full-blown language.
- uses [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) instead of timestamps.
- provides a minimal shell which implements the most useful Unix commands on all platforms: [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)), [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK), etc.
- works with either Unix or [DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS) style pathnames.
- extensively documented.
- supports parallel builds.
- fast.

Comment: Please update the link to OMake since it is not available anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I'll also second CMake. I've been using it for quite a while on a multi-platform project and I'm very satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic generation of (M|m)akefiles makes me worry about what you're trying to do here.

Do you understand what goes on under the covers when you type make? Or gmake? I'm only asking because if you don't when things break, such as new code changes not being incorporated into the build, you'll have difficulties trying to work what has happened.

To start to understand make, can I suggest having a read of "[Managing Projects with GNU Make](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596006101)" by Robert Mecklenberg. The early chapters cover how make is working. Getting your heard around the fact that make is backward chaining is one of the biggest things you can do.

If you don't, and your system appears to work, then you'll be, to use The Pragmatic Programmers' term, "[programming by coincidence](http://www.pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence)". (-:

BTW Great articles available at their site! And I'm not involved with them. YMMV. Yada-yada...

Answer (score 0):

One issue to consider is do you want a "makefile" creator or a replacement build system?  The problem with replacement build systems is that you typically don't get good IDE integration for platforms whose users expect this (Visual C++).
If you do want a makefile creator instead of a replacement build system, take a look at [MPC](http://ociweb.com/products/mpc).  It's free and open source.

Answer (score 0):

A recent addition to the list of make replacements is [waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/). From personal experience, SCons does the job pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar Makefile auto-generator projection called [CodeMate](http://dongli.github.com/CodeMate), developed by using Ruby. Maybe it is not that mature for large applications right now, but I will keep working on it to make it better.

Users should not need to edit any configuration file to build the software, or at least it is supposed to be. The learning curve should be minimized.

Comment: Yet another dead SO link! I manually went to your GitHub page, and what I see there as CodeMate is a Fortran-only build something. Did you create another project with the same name? [This](https://github.com/shepherddog/CodeMate) looks like it might be what you meant.