# What are the Makefile generation tools out there?

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm currently using a manually designed Makefile for my project and I have never used Makefile generators before. Note that I currently have more than 70 source files (C++, Python and MATLAB combined). The Makefile is mainly used to compile C++ files and the protocol buffers (.proto). I know my project is growing to have more and more files. They are currently all in one director. But I may need to have multiple directories. My fear is that maintaining a Makefile becomes harder and harder.

I used to see automake/autoconf before and I am seeing CMake more and more. What are the options? Are they designed large projects? Which one is preferred? What are pros and cons of each? What are the other good options?

I do see that automake is not listed in [any good tool for makefile generation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589/any-good-tool-for-makefile-generation). Is it outdated?

Comment: Please also tell us what you *need*.

Comment: How big is your project, and how portable does it need to be? Using `g++ -M` to generate dependencies can be quite useful, and if you don't have a huge number of files in the project, it's probably easier to use a manually made [or simple script/batchfile] than it is to learn and debug CMake or automake scripts.

Comment: Before anyone can reasonably answer this, it would help to know what you are hoping to accomplish and what doesn't work with plan makefiles today.  Are you trying to compile for multiple targets?  Or is your build environment sufficiently complex such that the existing Makefile is getting out of hand to maintain?

Comment: @MarkGarcia: I just updated the question.

Comment: Thanks and well done. Presenting your requirements and current constraints would pretty much narrow the answers to what you really *need*.

Comment: _'I do see that automake is not listed in any good tool for makefile generation?. Is it outdated?'_ Yes, somehow! I'm pretty sure you can achieve the same features CMake provides, but it's f***ing complicated to handle. The learning curve is pretty steep.

Comment: @g-makulik That why I am reluctant to learn CMake. I did not find a well cited tutorial for CMake.

Comment: @MohammadMoghimi I guess you misunderstood, I wanted to say **autoconf** has a steep learning curve. Regarding tutorials for using CMake I'm fine with [this one](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html) and the [latest reference](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 1st coming to mind are

- [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/)
- [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/)

What will fit better might depend on your particular needs. CMake covers a broad bunch of features from auto-building installable packages to unit tests, and is much more easier to understand than autoconf tools IMHO.

For really 'large' projects, that need integration of 3rd party stuff, generation of intermediate sources, etc. I'm actually using [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) + CMake to steer the C++ compilation parts. This also integrates well with contiguous integration servers like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).