# GCC/G++ compiler settings GUI

Tags: c++, user-interface, gcc, configuration, g++

I am looking for some frontend (GUI, Graphical user interface) for GCC and G++ which is oriented towards helping me setup the compiler in a user-friendly way.

I am not looking for a development environment, and the code edition is being made on a dedicated text editor (VS Code, Atom, whatever). I only want to compile my source and header files and change any compiler setting.

Comment: In what way is the thing you described not an IDE? What sort of setup are you looking to do graphically? And why?

Comment: Both the editors you mention have support for calling external programs that can be used to build the source code in the project.

Comment: I do **not** want code edition (syntax highlighting, project management and the like), debugger integration, code versionning, etc...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, but then you need to setup the compiler using the command-line, which I would prefer to avoid

Comment: @Magix you can use your imagination and pretend that the IDE doesn't support those things (I suppose highlighting is not easy to imagine away, but there should be a setting to disable it in most editors).

Comment: Regarding all the features you mention (which really make life as a developer much easier), don't the editors already have them as well? Especially syntax highlighing?

Comment: And you don't need to go into a command line, you can just edit special configuration files from inside the editors themselves, as well as editing possible makefiles or other build-system for the actual compilation. No need to leave the editor for the command line. It *will* be easier to handle with a full IDE of course, but still possible to do all inside the mentioned editors.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude True, but my point is all this is not a **graphical** compiler configuration

Comment: If you really need such a tool, then why don't you *make* it? If you have an itch, then scratch it. Many common programs was created for similar reasons, the programmer needed a tool to help him or her, so he or she wrote it.

Comment: I do not want to reinvent the wheel, so before developping the software (which I will do if I do not find one that suits me) I am trying to know if it exists. My friend Google sadly couldn't help me !

Comment: Then please take some time to review ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as such questions are clearly marked as off-topic there.

Comment: Possibly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589/any-good-tool-for-makefile-generation) can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Make to properly compile your files through a configuration (Makefile), but there is no GUI.
For more information : [make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

Comment: And to make your life easier, you can generate those makefiles with the autotools :D